# Sort an Array of struct by a value of a field inside the struct

Tags: c

I am trying to implement a GA, Genetic Algorithm and I need to do the selection stage, I have chosen first to order all individual **ann**s, I have the following structures

```
typedef struct ann {
    int inputs;                 /* Number of input neurones      */
    int hidden_layers;          /* Number of hidden layers       */
    int hidden;                 /* Number of hidden neurones     */
    int outputs;                /* Number of output neurons.     */
    int weights;                /* Total nof weigths(chromosomes)*/
    int neurons;                /* Total Number of neurones      */
    double *weight;             /* The weights(genotype)         */
    double *output;             /* Output                        */
    double fitness;              /* Total fitness of the network    */
    double *delta;
    actfun activation_hidden;   /* Hidden layer activation func  */
    actfun activation_output;   /* Output layer activation func  */
} ann;
```

and I also have an array of this struct, like this

```
ann *population = malloc ( population_size * sizeof(ann));

for( i = 0; i < population_size; i++ ){
    population[i] = *create( trainset->num_inputs, 1 , hidden, trainset->num_outputs);
}
```

When I pass this population array to the following function

````
void selection(ann* an, int size)
{

    int temp=0,j,i;

    for(i=1;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<size-i;j++)
        {
            if(an[j].fitness >an[j+1].fitness)
            {
                printf("swaped\n");
                temp=an[j].fitness;
                an[j].fitness =an[j+1].fitness;
                an[j+1].fitness = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I should be getting a sorted array with ascending fitness values like

20.3, 21.4, 22.6

but i get

22.6, 18.0, 20.3

and so on when I 
```
printf(" %f ", population[i].fitness); 
```

My Question is how can I properly sort this array?

Here is the (link)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604077/how-to-assign-an-array-of-structs]! to the question i asked before, that shows the code of function create
````

Comment: Unrelated, You may want to concern yourself with the nearly assured memory leak and/or undefined behavior you're instigating in the not-shown code of `create` ? (the `population[i] = *create(...);` is kind of a dead-give-away).

Comment: so what are the options i have?

Comment: For starters, include the code for `create` to verify that assessment. Second, create a [mcve]. Related directly to your post, your sort (oddly named `selection, odd being it is actually a bubble sort), is only swapping the `fitness *member* of the structures; the remaining members stay as-was. In other words, your sorting members, not full structures. If you want to sort the *structures* as complete entities based on `fitness` values, your swap should be swapping `a[j]` with `a[j+i]` using a temporary `ann`, not just the fitness members.

Comment: And fwiw, I can't believe this doesn't puke compiler warnings unless you're frankly not using any. `temp` is `int`, but `fitness` is `double`. That's a definite loss in precision.

Comment: @WhozCraig can you help now the create function code link is placed

Answer (score 2):

Is the standard library unavailable?

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>

int compareAnn(const void* a, const void* b)
{
  const ann* pa = (const ann*)a;
  const ann* pb = (const ann*)b;
  return pa->fitness - pb->fitness;
}

void selection(ann* an, int size)
{
  qsort(an, size, sizeof(ann), compareAnn);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `qsort()` function with a custom comparison function here. First, define the comparison function:

```
int compare (const void *_a, const void *_b) {
    ann *a = _a, *b = _b;
    return a->fitness - b->fitness;
}
```

then, sort the array itself:

```
qsort(an, size, sizeof(ann), compare);
```

This should result in the array sorted by the fitness criterion.